# jquery hide the errors if the input is validated

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i am showing errors if the input fields are not validated according to my condition and if the  fields are validated i want to hide the errors but i dont know how to hide the errors after showing up .

here is my code

```
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <div class = "error" style = "display:none">This field is required.</div> 

function send(){
   var name = $("#name").val();

if (name =="" || name == "Name"){
$(".error").show();
return false;
}else{

     //hide the errors if the user typed something correct 
}
```

i think i have to do some jquery inline validation but i don't know how can I do this here in my code..

Comment: i know this but it is not hiding after showing up

Comment: I would be great if you provide a fiddle for it. Along with How you are using `send()`

Comment: Working Demo try this   http://jsfiddle.net/bx8fF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();

 if (name =="" || name == "Name"){
 $(".error").show();
 return false;
}else{
  $(".error").hide();
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
var name = $.trim($("#name").val());

if (name =="" || name == "Name"){
$(".error").show();
return false;
}else{

   $(".error").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? :

```
function send(){
    var name = $("#name").val();

    if (name =="" || name == "Name"){
        $(".error").show();
        return false;
    }else{
        $(".error").hide();
        return true;
    }
}
```